# 2 users, 3 rdp sessions

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, rdp, session

We have Windows 2008 R2 Server Enterprise. 
And there are the 2 of us. We are log in together, each one on different session, to watch for processes via RDP. 
The sessions are : session 2 and session 3.

But today, my partner wants to change sessions, because on mine there was running something what he needs. So I close the window and he login again by clicking on rdp connection icon, on his physical machine

We were so much surprised, because he has connected to session 5.
So there was session 5 in which he login, session 2 empty (mine) and session 3 empty (his).

And now I am wondering, how to make this state, that there are 2 people and 3 sessions on Windows.

I know that there is some licence to make more people login together on windows server. But, we don't need more people, because there are two of us only, but I could make use of another session, to prepare things to make them easy accessed via login from one to another session.

But when We tried to copy that situation and couldn't. 
Do I have to have another machine?

Comment: You're limited to two active sessions at a time.  Inactive sessions don't count.  See also https://serverfault.com/q/581610/94065

Comment: Yes, i know about limited sesion. I said it myself. I am asking, how can I start third one session on one computer via rdp. 
Your link say opposite, it didn't help my case.

Comment: The link I provided shows you the setting that is preventing you from logging one user into two different sessions simultaneously.  The OP wanted to turn it on, you want to turn it off, but it's the same setting either way!  But my point was that you shouldn't have been surprised at having more than two sessions in total, because it is only the active sessions that count.

Comment: ... when you log on, Windows *may* reuse an existing empty session if one is available, but it doesn't *have* to.  In the situation you describe, Windows probably hadn't quite finished tidying session 3 up ready to be reused, so it created a new session instead.